# PrimeNG - Property 'length' does not exist on type 'TreeNode'

Tags: angular, primeng

Im trying to iterate my nodes to programmatically set the node to be selected. Selected nodes are stored in`selectedFile3` but it has no length so I cant iterate over it to find all selected nodes..

If I print `selectedFile3` to console it has length... Anyone have a clue in How to achieve this ?

```
<p-tree [value]="filesTree11" layout="horizontal" selectionMode="checkbox" [(selection)]="selectedFile3" [propagateSelectionUp]="true" [propagateSelectionDown]="false" (onNodeSelect)="test()"></p-tree>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
title = 'app';

filesTree11: TreeNode[];
selectedItems: TreeNode;
msgs: Message[];
arr: TreeNode[] = new Array();

constructor(private nodeService: NodeService) { }

ngOnInit() 
{                        
    this.nodeService.getFiles().then(files => {
        this.filesTree11 = [{
            label: 'Root',
            children: files
        }];
    });
}


test(node)
{
    console.log(this.selectedItems);
    console.log("length : " + this.selectedItems.length);

}
```

**Update**
There was an error in the example at https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/showcase/components/tree/treedemo.ts

```
selectedFile3: TreeNode; // should be TreeNode[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes `selectedFile3` has a length :

[Here is a working plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/4BJ55xNhjMD7yUAC8Qog?p=preview)

Can you give more details / share a plunker if it does not suit you please ?

Comment: Strange, your code works in the plunker. I have updated the question with my app.component.ts file

Comment: It was an error in the primeNG example https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/showcase/components/tree/treedemo.ts which had selectedFile3 defined as TreeNode, and not TreeNode[]